# Failed to start the Kernel. Kernel Python 3.11.1 is not usable

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I m unable to run .ipynb (Jupiter Notebook file) from VSCode. I am new to VScode and I'm not sure why?
Python version : 3.11.1

When I click the output tab it showed following Error: It says

```
'Kernel Python 3.11.1 is not usable'
#---------------------------------------------------#
error 13:21:58.722: Error in execution (get message for cell) [kp [Error]: Kernel Python 3.11.1 is not usable. Check the Jupyter output t
    at Um.waitForIdleOnSession (/Users/nipuni/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:17:131848)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Um.createNewKernelSession (/Users/nipuni/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:17:2750
    at async Um.connect (/Users/nipuni/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:17:273916)
    at async Km.startNew (/Users/nipuni/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:17:281707)
    at async a (/Users/nipuni/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:17:245682)
    at async lm.createNotebookInstance (/Users/nipuni/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:17:2458
    at async lm.createNotebook (/Users/nipuni/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:17:246529)
    at async Zm.createJupyterSession (/Users/nipuni/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.1.2010391206/out/extension.node.js:17:306419
  category: 'invalidkernel',
  kernelConnectionMetadata: Zd {
    kind: 'startUsingPythonInterpreter',
    kernelSpec: id {
      specFile: undefined,
      interpreterPath: '/usr/local/bin/python3',
      isRegisteredByVSC: 'registeredByNewVersionOfExt',
      name: 'pythonjvsc74a57bd0aee8b7b246df8f9039afb4144a1f6fd8d2ca17a180786b69acc140d282b71a49',
      argv: [Array],
      language: 'python',
      executable: 'python',
      display_name: 'Python 3',
      metadata: [Object],
      env: {},
      interrupt_mode: undefined
    },
    interpreter: {
      id: '/usr/local/bin/python3',
      sysPrefix: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11',
      envPath: undefined,
      displayPath: [f],
      envName: '',
      uri: [f],
      displayName: '',
      envType: 'Unknown',
      version: [Object]
    },
    id: '.jvsc74a57bd0aee8b7b246df8f9039afb4144a1f6fd8d2ca17a180786b69acc140d282b71a49./usr/local/bin/python3./usr/local/bin/python3.-m#i
  },
  vslsStack: [
    CallSite {}, CallSite {},
    CallSite {}, CallSite {},
    CallSite {}, CallSite {},
    CallSite {}, CallSite {},
    CallSite {}
  ]
}
[W 13:22:38.510 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 204ac218-8e43-4f52-a647-55804cd1ed98
[E 13:22:38.516 NotebookApp] Error opening stream: HTTP 404: Not Found (Kernel does not exist: 204ac218-8e43-4f52-a647-55804cd1ed98)
```

Comment: Did part of the first line of the error message get clipped off when you copied it to paste in your question post? or does it really just end like "_Check the Jupyter output t_"?

Comment: did you create 1 cell and try to run `print('hello world') ?  and if so, what do you get back then ?